# linux kernel how to check whether the sticky bit is set

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I am working on a linux kernel project whose intent is to modify the kernel to require that certain designated files (such as important system files or system configuration files) are validated before being executed (in case of a binary) or opened for read and write access.

Inside the kernel, we'll only provide validation for files whose sticky bit is set. So anyone
knows how to check whether the sticky bit of a file is set inside the kernel?

I searched through the website and only see answers about how to do that in user-land.

Answer (score 2):

See the [`check_sticky`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.8.2/fs/namei.c#L2203) function in `fs/namei.c`.